# Blackberry PIM Demo Setting the Alarm/Dialog Box/Reminder

Tags: blackberry, alarm, pim

I am using the PIM Demo sample from Blackberry inside my application to add event to the device's calendar. The problem is there is no reminder or any dialog boxes popped up when the event starts.

Is there any way to set this manually? Or is there anything wrong with the programs?

I would like to have any form of reminder, could be an alarm, dialog box, or even just a notification will do.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

To have a reminder you must set the Event.ALARM field in the PIM Event to the number of seconds before the start of the event you want the remider:

```
Event.set(Event.ALARM, 0, 0, 900);
```

Will set a reminder for 15 minutes before the event.

Comment: Where do I add this statement? Inside the onSave method? Or somewhere else?

Comment: Yes, somewhere before [`_event.commit();`](https://github.com/blackberry/JDE-Samples/blob/master/com/rim/samples/device/pimdemo/EventScreen.java#L333)